# How to collocate different spring major versions in a project?

Tags: java, spring

My project, call it A, depends on Project B

Project A

- Runs on JDK 17
- Uses spring-framework version 6.0.6

Project B

- Runs on JDK 11
- Uses spring-framework version 5.3.9 and spring-boot version 2.7.9

When Project B is added as a dependency in Project A, all of its spring transitive dependencies are overridden with a higher version. Which breaks Project B. Project A requires spring version 6 to run, we can't downgrade it.

- Normally the resolution would be to upgrade the JDK and spring version in project B (fairly sure things will break and not sure if it's worth the time retesting).
- Even if I am able to resolve this issue by upgrading project B's spring and jdk versions because I can control project B. How do I handle a similar situation when I have a 3rd party dependency on which I do not have any control?

Is there any way to collocate two different versions of spring-framework in Project A such that it uses the newer version of spring for Project A and the older version of spring for Project B?

Comment: It is generally not possible to directly collocate two different versions of the same library within the same application, as it can lead to conflicts and compatibility issues.

Comment: For many libraries you can get away with using shaded libraries (basically "private" copies of the libraries in different packages). I'm not sure if that'll work well with something as big and complex as Spring itself.